# Database Handler Class

Tags: php, object-oriented, security, database, mysqli

I've written this DB Handler class. Please review it and suggest any code edits or point out mistakes and security loop holes. Please also suggest a better way to handle things, if there is a security loop hole in there.

```
class db {

protected $dbHost;
protected $dbUser;
protected $dbPass;
protected $dbName;
protected $dbLink;

public function __construct ( $host=NULL, $user=NULL, $pass=NULL, $db=NULL ){

    $this->dbHost = $host? $host : 'localhost';
    $this->dbUser = $user? $user : 'root';
    $this->dbPass = $pass? $pass : '';
    $this->dbName = $db? $db : 'my_db_name';

    if( !($this->dbLink = mysqli_connect( $this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName) ) ){
        echo 'Error While Connection to DB: '.mysqli_error( $this->dbLink );
    }
}

public function __destruct(){
    if( ! mysqli_close($this->dbLink) ){
        echo 'Error While Closing Connection to DB: '.mysqli_error( $this->dbLink );
    }
}





/********************************************************************************

    1) This function is used to fetch data

    @param: $tableName [required]
    @param: $requiredColumns. This is an array like 'tableColumn', 'tableColumn', 'tableColumn'
    @param: $conditionsArray. This is an associative array like 'tableColumn' => 'value to check'
    @param: $orderBy. This is an array like 'tableColumn', 'ASC'

*********************************************************************************/
public function select( $tableName, $requiredColumns = NULL, $conditionsArray = NULL, $orderBy = NULL ){
    if( $requiredColumns == NULL || count($requiredColumns) <= 0 ){
        $col = '*';
    }
    else{
        $col = implode(', ', $requiredColumns);
    }

    $query = 'SELECT '.$col.' FROM `'.$tableName.'`';
    if( $conditionsArray != NULL ){
        $args = array();
        foreach( $conditionsArray as $key => $value ){
            array_push( $args , '`'.$key.'` = "'.$value.'"' );
        }
        //var_dump( $args );
        $where = implode( ' AND ' , $args );
        $query .= ' WHERE ' . $where;
    }
    if( $orderBy != NULL ){
        $order = implode(' ', $orderBy);
        $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$order;
    }
    //echo $query;
    return $this->execute( $query , 'resource' );
}





/********************************************************************************

    2) This function is used to insert record

    @param: $tableName [required]
    @param: $data [required] This is an associative array like 'tableColumn' => 'value to insert'

*********************************************************************************/
public function insert( $tableName, $data ){
    if( $data != NULL && count($data) > 0 ){
        $cols = ''; $vals = '';
        foreach( $data as $key => $val ){
            $cols .= $key.', ';
            $vals .= "'".$val."', ";
        }
        $cols = rtrim( $cols , ", ");
        $vals = rtrim( $vals , ", ");
        $query = "INSERT INTO `".$tableName."` (".$cols.") VALUES (".$vals.")";
        return $this->execute( $query, true ) ;
    }
}





/********************************************************************************

    3) This function is used to Update records

    @param: $tableName [required]
    @param: $data [required] This is an associative array like 'tableColumn' => 'value to insert'
    @param: $conditionsArray. This is an associative array like 'tableColumn' => 'value to check'

*********************************************************************************/
public function update( $tableName, $data, $conditionsArray ){
    if( $data != NULL && count($data) > 0 ){
        $args = array();
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ){
            array_push( $args , '`'.$key.'` = "'.$value.'"' );
        }
        $dataString = implode( ', ' , $args );
        $arr = array();
        foreach( $conditionsArray as $key => $value ){
            array_push( $arr , '`'.$key.'` = "'.$value.'"' );
        }
        $where = implode( ' AND ' , $arr );
        $query = 'UPDATE `'.$tableName.'` SET '.$dataString.' WHERE '.$where;
        return $this->execute( $query );
    }
}





/********************************************************************************

    4) This function is used to check number of records

    @param: $tableName [required]
    @param: $conditionsArray. This is an associative array like 'tableColumn' => 'value to check'

*********************************************************************************/
public function numRows( $tableName, $conditionsArray = NULL ){
    if( $conditionsArray == NULL ){
        $query = 'SELECT 1 FROM '.$tableName;
    }
    else{
        $args = array();
        foreach( $conditionsArray as $key => $value ){
            array_push( $args , '`'.$key.'` = "'.$value.'"' );
        }
        //var_dump( $args );
        $where = implode( ' AND ' , $args );
        $query = 'SELECT 1 FROM `'.$tableName.'` WHERE ' . $where;
    }
    //echo $query;
    $resource = $this->execute( $query , 'resource' );
    return mysqli_num_rows( $resource );
}





/********************************************************************************

    5) This function is used to DELETE

    @param: $tableName [required]
    @param: $conditionsArray [required] This is an associative array like 'tableColumn' => 'value to check'

*********************************************************************************/
public function delete( $tableName, $conditionsArray ){
    if( $conditionsArray != NULL ){
        $args = array();
        foreach( $conditionsArray as $key => $value ){
            array_push( $args , '`'.$key.'` = "'.$value.'"' );
        }
        //var_dump( $args );
        $where = implode( ' AND ' , $args );
        $query = 'DELETE FROM `'.$tableName.'` WHERE ' . $where;
    }
    return $this->execute( $query );
}





/********************************************************************************

    6) This function is used to login

    @param: $tableName [required]
    @param: $conditionsArray. This is an associative array like 'tableColumn' => 'value to check'

*********************************************************************************/
public function login( $user, $pass ){
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->dbLink, $user );
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->dbLink, $pass );
    $data = array( 'username' => $user, 'password' => md5($pass) );
    if( $this->numRows( 'users' , $data ) > 0 ){
        $result = $this->select( 'users' , NULL , $data );
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
}





/********************************************************************************

    7) This function is used to perform custom query

    @param: $query [required]

*********************************************************************************/
public function query( $query ){
    return $this->execute( $query );
}





/********************************************************************************

    8) This function is used to execute the queries

    @param: $query [required]
    @param: $return_type = 'bool' , 'resource' , 'id'

*********************************************************************************/
private function execute( $query , $return_type = 'bool' ){ 
    if( !empty($query) ){
        switch( $return_type ){
            case 'id' :
                if( mysqli_query( $this->dbLink , $query ) ){
                    return mysqli_insert_id( $this->dbLink );
                }
                else{
                    die(mysqli_error( $this->dbLink ));
                    return 0;
                }
                break;

            case 'resource' :
                if( $rs = mysqli_query( $this->dbLink , $query ) ){
                    return $rs;
                }
                else{
                    die(mysqli_error( $this->dbLink ));
                    return false;
                }
                break;

            case 'bool' :
                if( mysqli_query( $this->dbLink , $query ) ){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    die(mysqli_error( $this->dbLink ));
                    return false;
                }
                break;

            default :
                echo 'Invalid 2nd parameter (return format)';
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'Empty query not allowed.';
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The big thing that jumped out at me:  Why are you storing the connection info, when you use it right away in the constructor and then never touch it again?  You're just begging for a misplaced/forgotten `var_dump` to leak your database credentials.

Comment: You mean to say this line here:
`$this->dbLink = mysqli_connect( $this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName)`

I'm storing the connection info in `dbLink` and using this variable in almost every method below sir.

Comment: No, i mean like `$this->dbHost = $host ? $host : 'localhost';`, and the same for username, password, and DB name.  Once you've connected, you no longer need that info; you only needed it in the first place to build `$this->dbLink`.

Comment: You are kind of `right` :| 
I think I should make local variable in `constructor` for this purpose.

Comment: You hardly even need to do that; you already have four of them -- the parameters to the constructor -- which you already give nonsensical default values to.  You could instead say `public function __construct($host='localhost', $user='root', $pass='', $db='my_db_name')`.  (Though frankly, it'd be better to not have defaults at all.  That's per-app configuration info, and belongs in a config file.  And with default values, that opens up the possibility of only specifying half the settings, which wouldn't make sense.)

Comment: I'm also building a `config.php` file for common variables and `defined` constants though. I think I should include db credentials in that file, as every one is suggesting. Thanks mate :)

Comment: @OMI I wouldn't recommend that (see point one in the list in my answer). But if you do: Store the file that contains the db credentials outside the web root. Otherwise your credentials can leak in certain situations.

Comment: @tim so you mean i should use the credentials right away. without storing them in any local/global variable?

Comment: @OMI I'm not really talking about how you pass the values around, but how they get into your `config.php` file in the first place. And here, I would recommend against hardcoding them, but loading them from a configuration file (non-PHP) instead (if you hardcode them you would always need to be careful when sharing code, removing the password). And in either case, the file with the password should be outside the web root.

Comment: @tim okay right. So I should store the credentials in say `.txt` file, outside of the root and then read the file once when the app initiates, from PHP and store values in global/local variables, right?

Comment: @OMI yes, that's how I would do it

Comment: Great! so finally it settles down. I'm gonna do it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected $dbHost;
protected $dbUser;
protected $dbPass;
protected $dbName;
protected $dbLink;
```

Why protected? You except subclasses? Even with subclasses, why they could need to work with this fields?

The name `db` is sooo ugly. `Database` is better (even if too generic, but hey...)

```
$this->dbHost = $host? $host : 'localhost';
$this->dbUser = $user? $user : 'root';
$this->dbPass = $pass? $pass : '';
$this->dbName = $db? $db : 'my_db_name';
```

They are optional, why not put it directly in the constructor line?

```
public function __construct ( $host=NULL, $user=NULL, $pass=NULL, $db=NULL ){
```

will be

```
public function __construct ( $host="localhost", $user="root", $pass="", $db="my_db_name"){
```

Here

```
if( !($this->dbLink = mysqli_connect( $this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName) ) ){
    echo 'Error While Connection to DB: '.mysqli_error( $this->dbLink );
}
```

Why echo the error when you can `throw` the error?

```
throw new LogicException("Unable to connect to Database, error: " . mysqli_error ( $this->dbLink ));
```

Are you sure `$this->dbLink` will contains a reference to `MySQLi` and not `FALSE`? Reading your code i think it will be `FALSE`.

The same for `__destruct`.

```
/********************************************************************************

1) This function is used to fetch data

@param: $tableName [required]
@param: $requiredColumns. This is an array like 'tableColumn', 'tableColumn', 'tableColumn'
@param: $conditionsArray. This is an associative array like 'tableColumn' => 'value to check'
@param: $orderBy. This is an array like 'tableColumn', 'ASC'
```

*********************************************************************************/
Why so much `**********` this just looks ugly.

Here

```
$query = 'SELECT '.$col.' FROM `'.$tableName.'`';
```

you can't use `?` but you should filter your `$col` to be sure that it will not include any special char which could do any sql injection. The same for `$tableName`, in a project i used a an array where i saved all the table names which i allow to use, it the table is not in this list i throw an Exception. You could do something similar maybe?

The same for arguments, i suppose it's dynamic i was in a situations like yours but to avoid sql injection i still used mysqli_prepare (even if it doesn't allows you to use arrays)

It looks like this

```
public function commit($connection) {
    $finalParams = array ();

    $query = "UPDATE " . $this->table . " SET ";
    $paramTypes = "";

    if (count($this->mapChanges) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    foreach($this->mapChanges as $value) {
        $paramTypes .= $this->convertType($value);
    }

    // it will be the ID field
    $paramTypes .= "i";

    $finalParams[] = &$paramTypes;

    foreach($this->mapChanges as $column => &$value) {
        $query .= $column . " = ?,";
        $finalParams[] = &$value;
    }
    unset($value);

    //l'id da aggiornare
    $finalParams[] = &$this->id;

    // ultima "," sostituita con uno spazio vuoto
    $query[strlen($query) - 1] = " ";

    $query .= " WHERE id = ?";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt === false) {
        return -1;
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $finalParams);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    return $rows;
}

private function convertType($value) {
    $type = gettype($value);

    switch ($type) {
        case "boolean":
        case "integer":
            return "i";
        case "double":
            return "d";
        case "string":
            return "s";
        default:
            return "b";
    }
}
```

It's ugly, but does the job. It allows you to use dynamic arguments. Edit it if you want.

You could refactor your `execute` and avoid all this if blocks, something like

```
private function execute( $query , $return_type = 'bool' ){ 
    if (empty($query)) {
        echo "Empty query not allowed.";
        return false;
    }

    switch( $return_type ){
        case 'id' :
            if( mysqli_query( $this->dbLink , $query ) ){
                return mysqli_insert_id( $this->dbLink );
            }
            else{
                die(mysqli_error( $this->dbLink ));
                return 0;
            }
            break;

        case 'resource' :
            if( $rs = mysqli_query( $this->dbLink , $query ) ){
                return $rs;
            }
            else{
                die(mysqli_error( $this->dbLink ));
                return false;
            }
            break;

        case 'bool' :
            if( mysqli_query( $this->dbLink , $query ) ){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                die(mysqli_error( $this->dbLink ));
                return false;
            }
            break;

        default :
            echo 'Invalid 2nd parameter (return format)';
            break;
    }

}
```

Again, don't use `echo` to print errors but exception or specific return values.

```
die(mysqli_error( $this->dbLink ));
return false;
```

You `die`, the execution will stop. Inside an API, why you let my script die? I will do the die if i think i need to die. And stop echo's your errors. Noone wants to see your errors messages in the HTML page.

Comment: You mention it in your comment, but your code doesn't reflect this, so just for emphasis: the [table is also an attack vector for sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_SQL_Injection#WARNING:_Escaping_table_names) if it is user supplied.

Comment: Thank you for your time to read and provide a lot of feedback. I will take my time to read your feedback in detail and edit my code as per your suggestion, then I'll post back with questions, if any.

Comment: I took your advice:
changed `protected` to `private`.
put the db credentials in the constructor arguments as defaults.
`Are you sure $this->dbLink will contains a reference to MySQLi and not FALSE? Reading your code i think it will be FALSE.` you are right, if the connection fails then i have `false` in `dbLink` and it causes so much fatal errors. how to cope with this situation?

Comment: @marco aciemo ... your advice please?

Comment: Try to use `mysqli_connect_errno`, `mysqli_connect_error` according to PHP Dcoumentation.

Comment: used but of no use :(

Answer (score 11):

### Security

This code is not secure.

**SQL Injection**

You are trusting the user input completely (except in the `login` function where you do use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, [which is not secure enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)). Use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead. You should also read up on [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) in general.

**Other**

This is all minor in comparison to the SQL injection.

- [don't hardcode your password in the PHP code](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13353/password-in-file-php), store it in an external configuration file (outside the web root as otherwise your passwords will be exposed).
- don't echo complete errors to the user. Use a custom error string instead.
- `md5` is not a good enough hashing function, use something like `bcrypt` instead. (see for example [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5586/why-do-people-think-that-this-is-bad-way-to-hash-passwords) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/why-do-people-still-use-recommend-md5-if-it-is-cracked-since-1996))

### Code

**`query` function**

The `query` function just renames the `execute` function, and is thus useless. Also, you are not even using it. I would just remove it (and make `execute` public if you need to).

I think that you should fix the SQL injection issue before the rest of the code is reviewed, as it will change in a lot of places.

Comment: My bad I forgot to mention that the data will be sent here by a controller which will check for `SQL` injections.
But please do suggest whether i should handle `SQL` injections here or they are better off being handled in a separate controller?
Nice suggestion about `hasing` and `execute` function.

Comment: You should deal with sql injections here, not in the calling code (you cannot be sure that the caller always remembers this, and this is the logical place to do it). Also, here is what the owasp says about filtering vs prepared statements: [`this methodology [escaping user input] is frail compared to using parameterized queries`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3:_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input) (it goes on like this; escaping user input is NOT secure enough).

Comment: hmmmm right. I'll read this in detail and will post back for question. Thanks amigo :)